# How can I write crate-wide documentation?

Tags: documentation, rust

In order to ensure that all public artifacts of my crate are documented (if minimally to start with), I specified `#![deny(missing_docs)]` in my `lib.rs`. This backfired.

I expected to write a documentation comment at the top and the code afterwards:

```
/// Hello world example for Rust.

#![deny(missing_docs)]

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

This fails with:

```
error: an inner attribute is not permitted following an outer doc comment
 --> src/main.rs:3:3
  |
3 | #![deny(missing_docs)]
  |   ^
  |
  = note: inner attributes, like `#![no_std]`, annotate the item enclosing them, and are usually found at the beginning of source files. Outer attributes, like `#[test]`, annotate the item following them.
```

Reverting the order so that the attribute is first and the comment second:

```
#![deny(missing_docs)]

/// Hello world example for Rust.

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

Also fails:

```
error: missing documentation for crate
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / #![deny(missing_docs)]
2 | |
3 | | /// Hello world example for Rust.
4 | |
5 | | fn main() {
6 | |     println!("Hello world!");
7 | | }
  | |_^
  |
note: lint level defined here
 --> src/main.rs:1:9
  |
1 | #![deny(missing_docs)]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I could not find how to actually write documentation for the crate itself. How should I be writing the crate's documentation to satisfy `#![deny(missing_docs)]`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the hidden nugget in the [book's Publishing a Crate to Crates.io section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#commenting-contained-items).

Regular documentation comments (starting with `///`) document the *next* item, however a crate is nobody's next.

The solution is to switch to using another kind of comment, this time starting with `//!`, which documents the *enclosing* item.

And suddenly it works:

```
#![deny(missing_docs)]

//! Hello world example for Rust.

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: It is somewhat analogous to how attributes work (though I tried `///!` first).

Comment: @starblue: Yes, when I realized there was a `!` I found the resemblance with attributes striking; I think it shows well in the code sample given how close the two are together.